How to Migrate TFVS project to Azure Git Repos from different Organization
I want to migrate TFVC project which is exist in Org1 to Azure Devops Git Repos which is exist in Org2.
I tried to import it using Devops import repositry feature (that I find in dropdown of repos) but I could not. Some error are showing which is not understandable for me. Please refer below screenshot.


Refer to this doc: Import and migrate repositories from TFVC to Git

You can migrate code from an existing TFVC repository to a new Git repository within the same organization.

The Import TFVC to Git repo feature only supports migrating the repo in the Same Organization.
Based on your description, the TFVC and the Git repo are in different Organizations. So it will show the error in your screenshot.
To meet your requirements, you can migrate the TFVC Repo to Git Repo in Org 1 and then you can import the git repo from Org 1 to Org 2.
Here are the steps:
Step1: Migrate the TFVC Repo to Git Repo in Org 1

Step2: Copy Repo clone URL and import the git repo from Org 1 to Org 2.

On the other hand, you can also use the git tfs tool to do the migration.
